# Как разместить блог на сайте?

Tags: веб-программирование

На сайте нужно разместить блог руководителя. Точнее форму обратной связи, но только не посредством эл. почты, а чтобы посетитель сайта мог прямо на сайте оставлять свои вопросы. Я не силён в языках программирования. Кто нибудь может доходчиво объяснить, как это сделать (с помощью чего и тд., пошаговые инструкции приветствуются). Спасибо.

Comment: Если не селен в программировании то выхода 2:

1 - Заплатить денег для того чтобы сделали

2 - Последовать предложению @Shrek по поводу гостевой книги!

Comment: Да, да. я могу и на первое согласиться :) хехех.  +1 @Palmervan

Comment: @Shrek да не вопрос, я уже мысленно БД спроектировал)))

Comment: А я PHPшку написал :)

Answer (score 3):

Ну тут не 5 минут.

1. на сайте форму сделать чтобы юзвери могли отправлять данные
2. php файл на обработку этой формы
3. файл для вывода информации из БД на сайт (при ответе на вопрос)
4. административная панелька, чтобы можно было отвечать на вопросы
5. БД с таблицей для хранения данных.

ищи в сторону Гостевых книг :)

Answer (score 2):

Размещение блога.

1. Регистрируетесь на любом блогохостинге, который нравится, скажем blogger.com.
2. Прописываете у регистратора домена запись типа CNAME, указывающую на ghs.google.com.
3. Прописываете в настройках блога желаемое имя домена.
4. Все - блог на сайте! Далее настраиваете его по своему усмотрению.

Размещение системы обратной связи.

1. Находите платный или бесплатный движок, вроде [userecho](http://userecho.com/).
2. Аналогично регистрируетесь-размещаетесь.

или

1. Создаете официальную страницу-группу В Контакте.
2. Размещаете ссылку на группу на своем сайте.

Comment: Ну и зачем гонять посетителя сайта по всяким сервисам?